# Show div over image

Tags: jquery, css, image, firefox, z-index

I am trying to make a small store map with a pointer on it showing the location in the store. I have created this using jQuery and it works perfect in Chrome. Yet, in Firefox and internet explorer, the pointer is positioned behind the map and it is impossible to see the pointer. I know the pointer is there because I can see it using Firebug.

This is the html code I use:

```
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Location in store</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="../../maps/${department.getMap()}" id="map" />
                <div id="mapMarker" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="spacing" />
</div>
```

The css:

```
#map
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#mapMarker
{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;

    z-index: 3;
    content: url("../images/MapMarker.png");
}
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Set the marker on the map.
    $("#mapMarker")
        .css({
            "left":     25,
            "top":      25
        })
        .show();
});
```

Is there someone who can see why my pointer(#mapMarker) gets pushed behind the map?
Thanks.

Comment: `<td <JnJ:lang name="LocationInStore" /> />` what is that?

Comment: try using full closing tags.

Comment: Oh sorry, the site is made with jsp's and that is a tag we created ourselves. Those are not the problem.

Comment: why are you doing this `content: url("../images/MapMarker.png");` instead of `<img src="images/MapMarker.png" id="mapMarker" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use *background* property instead *content*

```
#mapMaker {
    ...
    background: transparent url("../images/MapMarker.png") left top no-repeat;
    ...
}
```

Works fine in Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/3xZuF/7/ (but not tested in IE yet)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the invalid markup, you are using:

```
<div id="mapMarker" />
```

That is not valid HTML, you need to close the div like so:

```
<div id="mapMarker"></div>
```

Correct this and it should work. Chrome is pretty good at interpreting invalid markup, firefox and IE are not as good. There are a few other errors, for example:

```
<td <JnJ:lang name="LocationInStore" /> />
```

and

```
<div class="spacing" />
```

Comment: If I close the div tag like that the pointer doesn't display in any of the browsers.

Comment: that doesn't mean this answer is wrong (because it's giving you correct advice).

Comment: @Jerodev, fair enough, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use valid markup. Try put what you have in a jsfiddle and I will have a look